# Append the nose @attr to the test name

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, nosetests

I am able to setup nose tests to run with the @attr tag. I am now interested in know if I can append to the end of the test name, the @attr tag? What we are trying to do is add a tag if our tests run into an issue and we write up a defect for it, we would then put the defect number as an @attr tag. Then when we run we could easily identify which tests have open defects against them.

Just wondering if this is even possible, and where to go to see how to set it up?

EDIT RESULTS RUNNING WITH ANSWER:[image]
[image]

Test Results:
[image]

So I sort of know what is going on, if I have the `@fancyattr()` at the class level it picks it up and changes the name of the class. When I put the `@fancyattr()` at the test level it is not changing the name of the test, which is what I need for it to do.

For example - Changes the name of the class:

```
@dms_attr('DMSTEST')
@attr('smoke_login', 'smoketest', priority=1)
class TestLogins(BaseSmoke):

"""
Just logs into the system and then logs off
"""

def setUp(self):
    BaseSmoke.setUp(self)

def test_login(self):
    print u"I can login -- taking a nap now"
    sleep(5)
    print u"Getting off now"

def tearDown(self):
    BaseSmoke.tearDown(self)
```

This is what I need and it isn't working:

```
@attr('smoke_login', 'smoketest', priority=1)
class TestLogins(BaseSmoke):

    """
    Just logs into the system and then logs off
    """

    def setUp(self):
        BaseSmoke.setUp(self)

    @dms_attr('DMSTEST')  
    def test_login(self):
        print u"I can login -- taking a nap now"
        sleep(5)
        print u"Getting off now"

    def tearDown(self):
        BaseSmoke.tearDown(self)
```

Updated screenshot with what I am seeing with `__doc__`:

[image]

Comment: To be more specific, do you want to modify test name with an attribute? I.e. `@attr('slow')` to turn `func_test` to `func_test_slow`?

Comment: @Oleksiy Yes, that is exactly it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it with args type attributes:

rename_test.py:

```
import unittest 
from nose.tools import set_trace

def fancy_attr(*args, **kwargs):
    """Decorator that adds attributes to classes or functions
    for use with the Attribute (-a) plugin. It also renames functions!
    """
    def wrap_ob(ob):
        for name in args:
            setattr(ob, name, True)
            #using __doc__ instead of __name__ works for class methods tests
            ob.__doc__ = '_'.join([ob.__name__, name])
            #ob.__name__ = '_'.join([ob.__name__, name])

        return ob

    return wrap_ob


class TestLogins(unittest.TestCase):
    @fancy_attr('slow')
    def test_method():
        assert True


@fancy_attr('slow')
def test_func():
    assert True
```

Running test:

```
$ nosetests rename_test.py -v
test_method_slow ... ok
test_func_slow ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.003s

OK
```

EDIT: For xunit reporting to work, test renaming should take place before running the test. You can do it on import, here is untested hack showing how to do it:

rename_test.py:

```
import unittest 

def fancy_attr(*args, **kwargs):
    """Decorator that adds attributes to classes or functions
    for use with the Attribute (-a) plugin. It also renames functions!
    """
    def wrap_ob(ob):
        for name in args:
            setattr(ob, name, True)
            ob.__doc__ = '_'.join([ob.__name__, name])

        return ob

    return wrap_ob


class TestLogins(unittest.TestCase):
    @fancy_attr('slow')
    def test_method(self):
        assert True


def make_name(orig, attrib):
    return '_'.join([orig, attrib])

def rename(cls):
    methods = []
    for key in cls.__dict__:
        method = getattr(cls, key)
        if method:
            if hasattr(cls.__dict__[key], '__dict__'):
                if 'slow' in cls.__dict__[key].__dict__:
                    methods.append(key)

    print methods

    for method in methods:
        setattr(cls, make_name(method, 'slow'),  cls.__dict__[key])
        delattr(cls, method)


rename(TestLogins)

@fancy_attr('slow')
def test_func():
    assert True
```

Comment: I modified slightly this line: `ob.__name__ = '_'.join([ob.__name__, name])` to be `ob.__name__ = str('_'.join([ob.__name__, name]))` since when I ran it without that it was giving me a type error saying `__name__` was expecting a string object.

Comment: I am not seeing the rename in my test results though.

Comment: It would help if you can provide a concrete example.

Comment: do I need an import statement for Nose in my test, like import Plugin or something for this to work?

Comment: Nope, it should work as is, it is a complete example. You would have to pass `-a` in order to select the test based on the attribute, but the way this is implemented makes running the test do the renaming, not the plugin activation.

Comment: Also, notice the way I coded it up it is only going to work for args lists `@attr('slow')` and not `@attr(speed='slow')` see attrib.py to see how to implement kwargs based attributes.

Comment: I have an `@fancyattr(DMSCORE-2330)` when I debug with the stop point on the `return ob` statement, I can see `ob` is returning the name correctly, with the item being appended correctly, however in the test results screen at the bottom of the PyCharm screen I am unable to see the appended name.

Comment: If I put the `@fancyattr()` at the class level, it changes the name of the class. When I put it at the test level though it doesn't change the name of the test, which is what I need it to do.

Comment: adding the `__doc__` I am still unable to get the attr in the test method name. See updated screenshot

Comment: I added renaming on import, it kinda feels like a total hack but it should work.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that out on Monday.