# Is there a way for a Python Nose test to know its decorated attributes?

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I have some tests like:

```
@attr('sanity', 'someothertag')
def test_this_important_feature(self):
    """Comment - Verify the very imporant feature
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to see the attributes on the test from inside the test. Alternatively (and probably preferably), is there a way to link the attributes of each test to each test that Nose finds? For the above example, it'd be something like:

```
test_this_important_feature: ('sanity','someothertag')
```

I run all of these tests and capture the results with nose.run(configuration) - would the results be able to have the attributes for each test?

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are directly available as a dictionary of the function, i.e. `test_this_important_feature.__dict__` will have all the attributes. Have a look at [get_attr_dict()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894584/read-nose-tests-arguments-in-a-file-especially-attr/20908432#20908432) in this answer, if you do not want to hardcode the name of the function. For the second part of the answer, you may also expand on [for fancy printout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869667/append-the-nose-attr-to-the-test-name/25880444#25880444)